# Insert a dynamic number of records from one table into another

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need to insert an equal number records from one table into another based on the number of rows in the table and the number of users in a table named 'users'. For example, if a table 'refunds_upload' has 100 records and table 'users' has 10 users, then I want to insert all 100 rows into table 'refunds' and assign each UserID 10 records each.

Currently, I'm just doing this

```
INSERT Refunds
    (BorrowerNumber, UserID)
    SELECT BorrowerNumber, 'unknown' FROM Refunds_Upload
```

This is a general outline of what needs to happen

```
 --get the list of users from the Users table
SELECT UserID FROM Users

--determine how many refunds each user gets
Declare @RefundsPerUser int
SET @RefundsPerUser = ROUND((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Refunds_Upload),2)

--For each UserID in Step 1...
INSERT INTO Refunds @RefundsPerUser INTO Refunds
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense - Why are you counting the users and dividing by the count of records in Refunds_Upload? This could be answered, but I fear this is not what you actually want done / haven't phrased the question well enough to get the answer you're looking for....

Comment: Yes, sorry, you're right. It should be: SET @RefundsPerUser = ROUND((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Refunds_Upload) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users),2)

Answer (score 0):

I can't say what you are doing makes sense, but here is how you would do it:

```
WITH refund_amt(amt) AS
(
  SELECT ROUND(COUNT(*)/MAX(RU.C),2) AS AMT
  FROM Users
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS C FROM Refunds_Upload) RU
)
INSERT INTO Refunds (BorrowerNumber, UserID)
  SELECT UserID, refund_amt.amt
  FROM Users
  CROSS JOIN refund_amt
```